# Correlation ID or trace ID in golang slog package

Tags: go, logging

I am using new golang slog package for outputting JSON. Here is my approach:

```
logger := slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, &slog.HandlerOptions{
    AddSource: true,
}))
slog.SetDefault(logger)
```

I set this in main function and then use slog where ever I need. The problem is I need to add a trace ID or Correlation ID so that when a request comes to an URL, I can search with that ID and can track all logs for that request.

I have tried this below code but it's not working:

```
ctx := context.Background()
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "hello", "world")
slog.InfoContext(ctx, "testing testing")
slog.InfoContext(ctx, "another testing")
```

I was following this article to [setup](https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/logging-in-go/) but couldn't find a way to configure tracer ID option. Another [article](https://darrenparkinson.uk/posts/2023-09-14-datadog-log-correlation-with-slog/) from datadog I was following but it doesn't have the full code.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply get the trace ID from the context, create a new logger with it, and use it:

```
traceId:=ctx.Value("traceId")
newLogger:=logger.With("traceId",traceId)
// use newLogger that will add traceId to all messages
```

Answer (score 4):

To log the trace ID automatically without having to pass a slog.Logger around, store the ID in a context and wrap the slog.Handler with an implementation that extracts it from the context for every log message. Make sure to always use the *Context variants of the logging functions.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log/slog"
    "os"
)

type contextKey int

const (
    traceCtxKey contextKey = iota + 1
)

func main() {
    var handler slog.Handler
    handler = slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stderr, &slog.HandlerOptions{
        AddSource: true,
    })

    handler = MyHandler{handler}

    slog.SetDefault(slog.New(handler))

    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, traceCtxKey, "123")

    slog.InfoContext(ctx, "message")
}

type MyHandler struct {
    slog.Handler
}

func (h MyHandler) Handle(ctx context.Context, r slog.Record) error {
    if traceID, ok := ctx.Value(traceCtxKey).(string); ok {
        r.Add("trace_id", slog.StringValue(traceID))
    }

    return h.Handler.Handle(ctx, r)
}
```

Output (formatted for readability):

```
{
  "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
  "level": "INFO",
  "source": {
    "function": "main.main",
    "file": "/tmp/sandbox3748904699/prog.go",
    "line": 40
  },
  "msg": "message",
  "trace_id": "123"
}
```

Try it on the playground: https://go.dev/play/p/rgjGXu7IG91