# Golang context variable is being overridden by another or parallel request

Tags: go, request

I am working on an app to handle webhook and for each request we attach an unique traceID to the `slog`. Here is my middleware:

```
func InitSlog(ctx context.Context, tracer *string, parentTracer string) (string, string) {
    logger := slog.New(
        slogFormatter.NewFormatterHandler(
            slogFormatter.HTTPRequestFormatter(false),
            slogFormatter.HTTPResponseFormatter(false),
        )(
            slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, &slog.HandlerOptions{
                AddSource: true,
            }),
        ),
    )
    //logger := slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, &slog.HandlerOptions{
    //  AddSource: true,
    //}))
    if tracer == nil || *tracer == "" {
        s := generateCorrelationID()
        tracer = &s
    }
    newLogger := logger.With("traceID", tracer, "parentTraceID", parentTracer)
    slog.SetDefault(newLogger)

    return *tracer, parentTracer
}
```

Here `parent traceID` means to track different process for a single webhook as we are creating google cloud task.

```
func Handlewebhook(c *gin.Context) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    traceID, _ := utils.InitSlog(c, nil, "")
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, constants.TraceIDKey, traceID)
}
```

This is my handler to handle webhook. When we receive multiple webhook at the same time, the `parent trace ID` gets overridden by another request.

I am passing the ctx to different function and there I get the traceID using the code `traceId, _ := ctx.Value(constants.TraceIDKey).(string)` and pass to the gcloud task to handle the webhook.

What could be the solution here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you retrieving the `parentTraceID` and setting it? The use of `slog.SetDefault(newLogger)` that you are initializing the logger globally, and this could lead to misbehavior when handling concurrent requests. A [minimal, reproduable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example really help us to replicate the issue in our end.

Comment: You're adding request-scoped attributes to the shared global logger. Either create a logger per request and pass that around, or wrap the JSONHandler with one that pulls the trace ID out of the context and adds it to each record. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77311769/correlation-id-or-trace-id-in-golang-slog-package/77314908#77314908

Comment: @Peter that question was also from me. I followed the answer.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC How should I do this to attach trace ID?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this sample snippet will help.
Since you are initializing the logger globally, it could lead to misbehavior when handling concurrent requests. Instead, we could use that logger with locally scoped fields.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log/slog"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

const contextParentTracerkey = "parent-tracer-span"

func generateCorrelationID() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("trace-%v", time.Now().UnixMicro())
}

func init() {
    logger := slog.New(slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stdout, nil))
    slog.SetDefault(logger)
}

func ContextLogger(ctx context.Context) (*slog.Logger, context.Context) {
    // get/check the previous tracer id for setting the parent tracer
    parentTracer, _ := ctx.Value(contextParentTracerkey).(string)
    tracer := generateCorrelationID() // new tracer id will generate each time

    // set the tracer in context, as this can be the parent for another one
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, contextParentTracerkey, tracer)
    return slog.With("traceID", tracer, "parentTraceID", parentTracer), ctx
}

func Handlewebhook(c *gin.Context) {
    // first level
    log, ctx := ContextLogger(context.Background())
    log.Info("Level - 1")

    // Calling another function with context
    func(ctx context.Context) {
        log, ctx := ContextLogger(ctx)
        log.Info("Level - 2 (parent level 1)")

        // Calling another function with context
        func(ctx context.Context) {
            log, ctx := ContextLogger(ctx)
            log.Info("Level - 3 (parent level 2)")

            // Calling another function with context
            func(ctx context.Context) {
                log, ctx := ContextLogger(ctx)
                log.Info("Level - 4 (parent level 2)")
            }(ctx)

        }(ctx)
    }(ctx)
}

func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.GET("/webhook", Handlewebhook)
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

**Output**

```
{"level":"INFO","msg":"Level - 1","traceID":"trace-1709877837339750","parentTraceID":""}
{"level":"INFO","msg":"Level - 2 (parent level 1)","traceID":"trace-1709877837339844","parentTraceID":"trace-1709877837339750"}
{"level":"INFO","msg":"Level - 3 (parent level 2)","traceID":"trace-1709877837339851","parentTraceID":"trace-1709877837339844"}
{"level":"INFO","msg":"Level - 4 (parent level 2)","traceID":"trace-1709877837339856","parentTraceID":"trace-1709877837339851"}
```

Comment: I have to use the slog in other functions. Can I just use slog there?